# BluRay DVD won't play "Missing AACS configuration file"

Tags: dvd

I am running Ubuntu MATE and am trying to get a BluRay DVD to play. I have VLC installed and but when I try to open the DVD I get the error message

> BluRay error. Missing AACS configuration file. Your input can't be opened.

How can I fix it?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "blu ray dvd", it's either a BluRay disc or a DVD disk. Please [edit] the question to correct the media and also post your Ubuntu release/version.

Comment: It's probably due to your Blu Ray disc being encrypted. Playing protected DVDs used to be a pain on Linux back in the day, until protection was cracked. Problem is, the majors learned from this the wrong way, and made a new system that's even more of a pain. IIRC, any Blu Ray reader such as VLC, must be given an authorisation key to be able to read protected Blu-Rays, and that requires the payment of a license. A shame ? Well, yes. I don't post this as an answer, since I suppose you would like a solution, which I don't have.